# RE46C180 -- disabling chamber checks

Tags: circuit-design, passive-networks, reverse-engineering

There are two types of things one can hook up to the interconnect wiring of a multiple station smoke detector: smoke alarms (with their own detection chamber, control chip, and horn) and auxiliary devices (such as relays) that trigger another function when they  receive a suitable signal on the interconnect line.  Furthermore, modern smoke detectors are either microcontroller-based (using a specialized AFE IC and a generic processor), or use a dedicated smoke detector IC, to the best of my understanding.

With that said, and the fact that modern dedicated smoke detector ICs include supervisory functions designed to check for the presence of a functioning smoke detection chamber, how does one build an auxiliary device (such as a relay module) to work with said dedicated smoke detector ICs?  Am I better off reverse-engineering the interconnect protocol of a given IC family, or trying to "trick" a modern smoke detector IC into seeing that a smoke chamber is present when it really isn't?

Specifically, I have a few Microchip RE46C180s in front of me, and I've tried shorting the CHAMBER and DETECT pins together, as in the schematic below, but that causes the alarm to chirp.  Is there some sort of passive network I can use between those two pins that'll emulate a functioning ionization chamber well enough that the chip will stay happy enough to let me use its IO functionality?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQJCzc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: As I understand, the chamber acts like a high impedance voltage divider and the IC gives alarm if the measured sensor grid voltage drifts away from a long time average or cell specific value. It will probably measure the cell current as well.